# The rectangle size inside a skewed container

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

Is there any way or calculation to find out the block size of a container with `transform: skew();`?

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

What I have been doing trial and error so far but as you can see it is not dynamic and sometimes it goes furhter than the edges.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(-20deg);
  background: lime;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(20deg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 81%;
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the structure you asked for but similar, and it does not get require any complicated calculation.

The principle would be to not get the child into the skewed block, but on top as you are on absolute position.
So we would have 3 blocs of the same size stacked. 
If you skew the 2 blocs behind, you get only half of the triangles. To get the full triangles, you can play with `transform-origin`, and you may achieve the following:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: pink;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  opacity:0.7;
}

.container-l,
.container-r {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(-20deg);
  transform-origin:50% 0%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
.container-l {
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  background: lime;
}
.container-r {
  transform-origin:50% 0%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-r">
</div>
<div class="container-l">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have said that the skewed container has an transition and is interactive. But thanks for the solution, it gives me an idea for an workaround.

Comment: I believe transitions should not be complicated to add to this structure. But for sure to get a proper answer all the constraints should be mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

First let's keep the width to be `100%` and simply adjust the origin of the transformation to have this:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(-20deg);
  background: lime;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(20deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now the part we need to remove is the one in red like shown below:

[image]

Considering the illustration we have `tan(angle) = X/H` where `angle` is the angle of skewing (`20deg`) and `H` is the height and X what we are looking for. So we need to remove `H*tan(20deg) = 0.36369*H`:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(-20deg);
  background: lime;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(20deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 0.3639*50vh);
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now that we have the good width we rectify the position:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(-20deg);
  background: lime;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 0.3639*50vh);
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

I am not really sure about the purpose of this shape but here is another idea to create this without complex calculation:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,lime 50%) left/15% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 49.8%,lime 50%) right/15% 100%,
    linear-gradient(lime,lime) center/70% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.child {;
  height: 100%;
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You simply have to make the inner rectangle the same width as the centred gradient (`70%` in this case) then you split the remaining to the left/right gradient that will create a triangular shape.

You can also easily apply some animation:

```css
body,
html {
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.8%,lime 50%) left/15% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 49.8%,lime 50%) right/15% 100%,
    linear-gradient(lime,lime) center/70% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition:1s;
}

.child {;
  height: 100%;
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition:1s;
}

.container:hover {
  background-size:0% 100%,0% 100%,100% 100%;
}

.container:hover .child{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```